# Конфликт кавычек html кода внутри JavaScript переменной

Tags: javascript, html

Есть переменная, в которой расположен кусок html кода.

**Вопрос**, какие языковые приемы использовать дабы избежать конфликта двойных и одинарных кавычек. Пример кода ниже, если его обернуть в одинарные кавычки или двойные, то это приведет к конфликту, перенос строк делает код сложнопонимаемым.

```
template = <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='name'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Экранируйте с помощью обратного слеша `\` те кавычки, которыми ограничен текст переменной.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! То что нужно.